# Scroll to element breaks with ajaxify_rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have ajaxified my site using the [ajaxify_rails](https://github.com/ncri/ajaxify_rails) GEM. Before ajaxification I had a page with logic to scroll to a particular element on clicking a link. Eg:

```
= link_to :some_element.l, "#some_element_id"
.
.
.
%div{:id => "some_element_id"}
```

So, on clicking **Some Element** link, the page was supposed to scroll to div with **id** as **some_element_id** with URL like:

> http://****.com/documentation#some_element_id

But, after ajaxifixcation, it tries to hit the above URL and shows me a blank page. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, in the documentation, it's written in **Requirements** that:

> Your app doesn't use named anchors (#). Named anchors can't be
>   correctly represented in the fallback hash based url scheme.

I wanted to check for a work around. But, I guess nothing I can do to support named anchors. I'll have to change my logic.

**EDIT**

Updated logic

**View**

```
= link_to :some_element.l, "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "scroll_to_element('some_element_id');"
```

**Javascript**

```
function scroll_to_element(element_id) {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery("#" + element_id).offset().top
  }, 100);
}
```